# Printing Schemas in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, printing, schema

I'm on microsoft sql server management studio 2008 10.0.1600.22
I have a number of databases (the things that have a can icon in Object Explorer), Each of these Databases contains several folders with generic dames like; Databases, Security, Server Objects, Replication, Management, and lastly SQL Server Agent. Inside the "Databases" folder, there are a large number of databases which each have their own columns/rows etc...

So for example

```
BLOCK1 (SQL Server ##.#.####)
[-]Databases
.[+]System Databases
.[+]Database Snapshots
.[-]GROUP1
..[+]Database Diagrams
..[-]Tables
...[+]System Tables
...[+]dbo.Table1
...[+]dbo.Table2
...[+]...
...[+]dbo.TableN
.[-]GROUP2
..[+]Database Diagrams
..[-]Tables
...[+]System Tables
...[+]dbo.Table1
...[+]dbo.Table2
...[+]...
...[+]dbo.TableN
...
.[-]GROUPN
```

Is there any high level built-in command or utility I can use to print out the schema for  each entire 'Block'?

I want a directory or 'map' of some sort I can use to see what Tables are within each Databases within each block. Expanding each database to see the contained tables often causes Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to freeze so having a printed secondary 'map' would be very useful in figuring out where things need to be done in a relatively LARGE network where finding out table names can take a very long time (loading/crash/freeze) or be functionally untenable.

I don't need column names; I can query the table to get that; I just need an easy way to see all the table names quickly to navigate and target queries. This is for work purposes; This RDBMs is extremely large and queries function fine against it; but expanding it to see where to target queries is impractical in object explorer due the extremely large number of components which clicking the [+] next to a database name is more likely to crash SQL server than return useful information if not taking a minute or so to load all the table names.

I know the simple but time consuming way to get this information; I'm just wondering if MS SQL Mgmt Studio 2008 might happen to have some built in function to just generate this list in plain text so I can print it out?

Answer (score 0):

There are several "Object Catalog Views" in SQL Server that contain the names and types for the system objects (as well as other info).  The one you may be most interested in is `sys.objects`, although there are others (`sys.tables`, `sys.columns`, etc.).

Here is a very generic example query:

```
use AdventureWorks2008
go
select      *
from        sys.objects as o
order by    o.type
```

For more info, see the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, this doesn't seem particularly more effective than just using SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES (nolock)
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
order by TABLE_NAME asc for each block. I've already finished this project doing it by repeating the above query

Comment: No, it wouldn't be any more effective.  What you did is the same as what I wrote, except you're iterating over it in chunks.

Answer (score 0):

nvm just did it by looping

SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES (nolock)
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
order by TABLE_NAME asc

and putting it in charts. this is more an issue of finding a better file format to store it in because the excel schema is 175MB large and would be 313k+ pages if physically printed. This initiative needs to re-examined from another angle. question closed